# How can I teach my dog to relax when outdoors?

Tags: dogs, behavior

Hi we have a two year old mongrel dog from the pound, she is mixed with collie/retreaver. She is very nervous and anxious except when she is next to me. I believe she had a bad start in life.  My problem is that we have a big garden and every time I put her outside with our other dog she whines to get back indoors. I tell her stop and she does for about 5 mins, she doesn't settle down outside and continually whines at the door and paces up and down whining until she can get into the house. It is an enclosed garden so she is safe and I would love her to just relax and enjoy being outdoors. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like separation anxiety, just a bit reversed (most often the dogs have to stay inside alone).

Just look up any other question regarding that topic to get more hints and suggestions.

But in short:

- Put your dogs outside.
- Play a bit with them, then leave.
- After just a minute or so, return and continue playing.
- Repeat the whole thing daily with increased time spans of being away.
- After a while your dog will learn, that you'll always return.